# Touch Event on UTableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitouch

There I need to add touch event on UTableViewController

Like there will be an image w.r.t. to each UICell, so when user touches any cell corresponding image will be visible to user, Image will only visible to user screen has touch event on it.  When user put finger up from screen, image will be hidden again.

Please guide to achieve this

Comment: corresponding image will be visible to user means will it have appear in a seprate view like popup? Please express your requirement clearly

Comment: Image will be shown in same view
Action will be like
user touch -> imageview visible in entire view 
touch remove  -> imageView will be hidden again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your image using UILongPressGestureRecognizer.You can add gesture to your cell and you can change your image in hangleLongPress method.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;  //user must hold for 1 second
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];


- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
      {
         // ----------------- Make here image visible ----------
      }

      if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
      {
         // ------------ Make here image invisible ----------
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes It is quite close,but how can i make image visible immediately like UILongPressGestureRecognizer needs to touch and hold the screen for some time.

Comment: You can add UITapGestureRecognizer instead of UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: According to me save your indexPath and change image on particular row.

Comment: @prasad he is saying i wanna hold that cell for some time in that case i wanna make image visible.

Comment: thanks Dharmbir Choudhary , I was missing minimumPressDuration :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use UIButton inside the cell for showing the image. It will make the implementation easier. 
You can implement like:

- initially set the button's background colour to be clear colour. This will make it look like hidden.

  ```
   button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  ```
- Set the Image on button as :

  ```
   [button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  ```

  This will show the image only 
  when button is pressed once touch is left it will hide automatically.

Hope it works for you.